# Make.com Wordpress integration returning 404 with REST API conection

Tags: wordpress, rest, http-status-code-404, integration, make.com

Since I updated the Wordpress CMS to 6.2 the MAKE.COM connection with Wordpress went broke, and cannot GET actionable the information through the Rest API for the new Wordpress Make modules .

> [404] No se ha encontrado ninguna ruta que coincida con la URL y el método de la solicitud. (error code: rest_no_route).

[Rest API 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXYwI.jpg)

Nevertheless, the old Make **Legacy **Wordpress are partially working, at least they can post on the site:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJBjW.jpg)

So it seems it may have something to do with the structure of the info that cannot get parsed correctly

[Make GET posts from Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxl0I.jpg)

I have disabled most of the plugins (just left make and Content Studio plugins), but the problem continues...

Any idea about what to do?

Answer (score 0):

It solved suddenly, probably some update on Make´s end...

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).